$3$-manifold that is a surgery on a knot
By the Lickorish-Wallace theorem, every oriented closed $3$-manifold can be obtained by a surgery on a link in $S^3$. In the statement of this result, links are required: not every such manifold can be obtained by a surgery on a knot in $S^3$. One way to see this is that $H_1(S^3_{p/q}(K))$ is cyclic for any knot.

What are some other necessary or sufficient conditions on a $3$-manifold to be a surgery on a knot in $S^3$?

The same question can be asked if we restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{Z}HS^3$. I am aware of some strengthenings of the Lickorish-Wallace theorem from the work of Hilden and Matveev, but they still require links.

What is some $\mathbb{Z}HS^3$ that cannot be obtained by a surgery on a knot in $S^3$? Is there a characterization of $\mathbb{Z}HS^3$s that can be obtained by a surgery on a knot in $S^3$? If not, what are some necessary or sufficient conditions?

I know that these questions are equivalent to asking which surgery diagrams can be reduced to knots by the Kirby moves, so I do not expect a complete classification exists.

Are there any partial results for branched double covers of knots?


This is an extensively studied question and is far from being understood in general. Here are some other conditions beyond the fact that $H_1(M)$ is cyclic.

the fundamental group should have weight 1, that is it is trivialized by adding a single relation, since killing the meridian of the knot kills the fundamental group (and hence that of any Dehn surgery)

If $H_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}$, then $M$ must be irreducible by Property R. Other obstructions are known.

If $M$ is reducible, then the number of connected summands is at most 3. The cabling conjecture would imply that the manifold must be a connected sum of a surgery on a knot and a lens space and in principle would reduce to the prime case.

If $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-homology 3-sphere, then it must have a non-cyclic $SU(2)$ representation. Examples of rational homology spheres with weight 1 fundamental group and no non-cyclic $SU(2)$ representation are known and which are not dehn surgery on a knot.

If $M$ is a rational homology sphere then it must bound a definite 4-manifold. Examples of rational homology 3-spheres which bound no definite 4-manifold are known.

If $M$ has finite fundamental group (so is spherical), then it is known precisely which such manifolds are obtained by Dehn surgery on a knot.


Aside from these general considerations, there are families of manifolds that are known not to be surgery on a knot. There are new examples using Furuta’s $\frac{10}{8}$ theorem. There are also announced examples of arbitrarily large surgery number.

About your third question:

Are there any partial results for branched double covers of knots?

The Montesinos trick tells you that if $K$ has unknotting number 1, then its double cover is $\pm\frac{\det K}2$-surgery along a knot $J$. So, for homology spheres, if $\det K = 1$, then $\Sigma_2(K)$ is a $\pm\frac12$-surgery along some knot $J$.
